Tailwind CSS (Blazor) flex-row and content alignment?
After reading thru Tailwind CSS documentation, I seem to be at a road block on how to get my content to align (bottom/baseline).


<div class="flex flex-row gap-4 flex-nowrap">
    <!-- Date Range primarily used for printing -->
    <div class="basis-1/2">
          <TelerikDateRangePicker @bind-StartValue="@_initialBeginDateRange"
                                  @bind-EndValue="@_initialEndDateRange"
                                  Min="@_minDate"
                                  Max="@_maxDate"
                                  AllowReverse="false" />
    </div>
    <!-- Buttons still will not align bottom or baseline -->
    <!-- Refresh by Date Range -->
    <div class="basis-1/4">
          <WcButton class="px-2 py-1 text-sm" Type=ComponentValue.ButtonType.Button OnClick="@FilterOnDateRange">Filter on Date Range</WcButton>
    </div>
    <!-- Print Schedule -->
    <div class="basis-1/4">
          <WcButton class="px-2 py-1 text-sm" Type=ComponentValue.ButtonType.Button OnClick="@Print">Print</WcButton>
    </div>
</div>



End result is:

I've been using Tailwind docs here
I'm new to Tailwind CSS.  Gone thru several tutorials but they mostly cover installation and setup and none div into real world examples and problems/solutions.
My objective is to have the two buttons align bottom/baseline rather than top.  I've tried all combinations but can't seem to get the content alignment the way I want it ... perhaps it's something odd with the TelerikDateRangePicker but any suggestions are welcome.

I was able to resolve the issue by resorting to straight HTML table using rowspan.


<table>
    <!-- Date Range primarily used for printing -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <TelerikDateRangePicker @bind-StartValue="@_initialBeginDateRange"
                                    @bind-EndValue="@_initialEndDateRange"
                                    Min="@_minDate"
                                    Max="@_maxDate"
                                    AllowReverse="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Refresh by Date Range -->
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0.4rem">
            <WcButton class="px-2 py-1 text-sm" Type=ComponentValue.ButtonType.Button OnClick="@FilterOnDateRange">Filter on Date Range</WcButton>
        </td>
        <!-- Print Schedule -->
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0.4rem">
            <WcButton class="px-2 py-1 text-sm" Type=ComponentValue.ButtonType.Button OnClick="@Print">Print</WcButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>




In a flex container, you can use items-end to make all child elements bottom-aligned.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row flex-nowrap gap-4 items-end">
  <!-- Date Range primarily used for printing -->
  <div class="basis-1/2">
    <div class="h-16 bg-red-200"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Buttons still will not align bottom or baseline -->
  <!-- Refresh by Date Range -->
  <div class="basis-1/4">
    <div class="h-8 bg-green-200"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Print Schedule -->
  <div class="basis-1/4">
    <div class="h-8 bg-blue-200"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Hi Karson, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I had already tried "items-end" and it didn't work.  I'm using version 3.4.13 of Tailwind CSS.  I suspect it's the TTelerikDateRangePicker control that somehow preventing the correct alignment.
